# Passing array variables between scopes

Tags: c++

My first ever question. On 'maning-up' to learn c++ I have myself in a tangle over scope. My understanding is that variables defined in functions should cannot be passe dout of scope. But I have been this like the  below A LOT and it works everytime with no problems. What am i missing?

I have defined some inline functions in ns1.cpp like so:

```
namespace ns1 {

inline void func1(float x[3]);

}

ns1::func1(float x[3]){

//(do stuff to x)

}
```

Within a function far far away in class_a.cpp i consume typically like this:

```
include "ns1.h"

...

void class_a::func2(){

float f[3];

ns1::func1(f)

//f comes back in great shape! No runtime or compilation errors or anything.

}
```

My hunch is that either a) as the functions in ns1 are inline the compiler is putting the instructions for func1 within the scope of func2 and somehow not causing out of scope type errors or, b) im getting lucky and there are behaviour problems ahead of me.

EDIT: I made his question too complex. For brevity I meant "Can you create variables in one function/scope and send them out of scope to parameters of another function/different scope?". BAsed Mooing Ducks' answer below I can see how an array would work if a pointer was sent and a function altered the data the pointer was pointing to. But is it bad form to create other variable types like int, char, in one scope/function  and send to another function as a parameter?

Comment: This will happen regardless of `inline`, so that's a red herring. `inline` also doesn't mean what you think it means :)

Comment: Also, if the function accepted a plain `float` instead of an array, would you expect that to work, or would you see that as the same thing?

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde 'this will happen regardless' meaning this will work everytime regardless of inline?

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde, I have been using array a lot so thought that might be relevant. I would expect ANY variable defined within func2 to fail regardless of type as it is out of scope. But it works, everytime.

Comment: (I'll put this in the comments since it doesn't cover the meat of the question) "But is it bad form to create other variable types like int, char, in one scope/function and send to another function as a parameter?" No, that's not bad form. The entire purpose for parameters is to be able to send stuff to functions.

Comment: Best advice I can give you: don't use C-style arrays, period. They are clumsy and error prone due to the very reasons you've pointed out. In modern C++ (after 11) use `std::array<T, N>` for fixed-size arrays, and `std::vector<T>` for dynamic arrays (there are almost 0 reasons to use `operator new[]`). In C++20 you also get `std::span<T>` (or use `gsl::span<T>` in previous revisions), which is basically a glorified pointer to a sequence of `T`s.

Comment: _But is it bad form to create other variable types like int, char, in one scope/function and send to another function as a parameter_ - No, this is how you are supposed to write stuff. In modern C++ you often pass stuff by-value to a function (often using move semantics - I highly recommend you learn how to use `move` well), or return something by value (thanks to NRVO). It's not _that_ frequent as it was before to see pointers in modern C++, especially now that we have fancy stuff like `string_view` and `span`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has a *really* stupid quirk where functions cannot take a array by value as a parameter.

```
inline void func1(float x[3]); //x isn't actually an array :(
```

Normally, all parameters are copies of the values. Except for arrays. Instead, C++ silently converts all array-value parameters to be just pointers. So it's actually:

```
inline void func1(float* x);
```

You'll even find that `sizeof(f)` in `func2` is about 12 (an array of 3 floats, which are each ~4 bytes), and `sizeof(x)` in `func1` is about 8 (a pointer), even though they both look like they're the same type, which really causes issues if you're not careful.

Also, since arrays can silently decay to pointers, `func1` is able to modify the `f` variable in `func2` via this pointer.

```
void class_a::func2(){
float f[3];
ns1::func1(f); //f decays to a pointer, so it passes a pointer to the first item.
```

This is super surprising even to experienced C++ developers, and why we learn to virtually never pass an array by value. Instead, pass a pointer explicitly (`float* x, int size`) , or an array by reference (`float (&x)[3]`), or a `std::array` (`std::array<float,3> x`), any of which behaves intuitively.

---

Interesting sidenotes:

```
void class_a::func2(){
float f[1024];
ns1::func1(f); //f decays to a pointer, so this also compiles :(
```

So definitely prefer to avoid array parameters-by-value.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information that will be useful to know. I think my question was more basic and should have just been "Can you create variables in one scope (function) and pass as parameters to another in the C++ rulebook?" Can you?

Comment: @slexov: Pass-by-value should have been named pass-by-copy, which is clearer that it's a different variable than the caller had. However, pass-by-reference will pass a _reference_ to the caller's variable, allowing the callee to modify it. (As observed by the `float (&x)[3]` sample.

Comment: Ah I think i feel some neurons connecting. So when you create a variable in one scope and 'send' it to another you are actually sending a copy of it. Array is different because you are sending a pointer rather then a copy of the array?

Comment: @slexov: Yes. By default, parameters are always copies. But you can also send references or pointers as parameters, and either will allow you to modify the variable they refer to, regardless of where it is or who owns it. Arrays are the nasty exception, because it _looks_ like it should be a copy, but it actually passes a pointer :(

Comment: Fortunately for me that is exactly the behaviour I want!

Comment: @slexov: Prefer to use `(float* x, int size)`, or `(float (&x)[3])` parameters then, which do the same thing, but are clearer, and don't allow mistakes.

Comment: Thank you once again. I wonder if the later option would prevent/stop the user from being able to modify memory beyond the size parameter either in IDE, compile, or runtime.

Comment: @slexov: neither prevents the user from reading past the end, unfortunately, but both make it more obvious that the length can be trusted to be accurate.

Comment: About as functional as a comment then.

Comment: @slexov: They're slightly better, on the caller side. `(float* x, int size)` requires the caller to pass in the size or they get a compiler error. And they're extremely likely to pass the right size.  `(float (&x)[3])` requires the caller to pass in an array that's the right size. You're right that within the callee they're all equally unsafe. Though the third may produce compiler warnings if you're lucky.

Comment: Thanks again. That's thrice. Very concise. I'll upvote as soon as I have the cachet.

Comment: Just thinking about it further: if I were storing multiple ```a[3]``` as ```a[10][3]``` for example then presumably I could pass a pointer for a 'slice' of this array like```*a[3][0]``` with size ```int 3``` to the callee with the first option whereas the latter option would create a compiler error if I did this?

Comment: @slexov You can easily pass any of multiple `float[3]` via either method. The advantages are that `(float* x, int size)` lets a caller choose to pass in a `float[4]` if they wanted, and that `float(&x)[3]` will _require_ the caller to pass in a `float[3]`. If the parameter type is a `float x[3]`, then the caller can pass in any `float*`, which the implementation certainly won't be expecting.

Comment: _C++ silently converts all array-value parameters to be just pointers_ - that's because it's what C does. This is the reason why modern C++ is supposed to use `std::array<T, N>` instead of C arrays, which are sloppy and error prone due to them being second-class citizens.